# Option for removing 'transfer content to' when deleting a user?

Tags: admin

Is there an easy way of disabling the 'transfer content to' option when deleting a user from the admin portal? In my use case, I want users content to always be completely deleted when they are removed from the site.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a clean way without hacking core Craft files (which is generally not advisable).

Sounds like a reasonable [feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com), though!

Comment: Added as a feature request.